# add parentheses to lowest and highest number in an array of strings

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

This code that will create a `p` element for every index in an array and it will put a parantheses on the lowest and highest number in an array

```js
const liArray = [5.6, 8.7, 1.3, 10, 56];
const min = Math.min.apply(Math, liArray);
const max = Math.max.apply(Math, liArray);
const parentElement = document.getElementById("myDiv");

liArray.forEach((currentValue, index) => {
  const elm = document.createElement('p');
  let text = `${index + 1}. ${(currentValue == min || currentValue == max) ? `(${currentValue})` : currentValue}`;
  elm.innerText = text;
  parentElement.appendChild(elm);
});
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

but my array is like this

```js
const liArray = ["5.6 hello", "8.7 hi", "1.3 hey", "10 hi", "56 hello"]
```

and i want to also add parentheses to the lowest and highest number and output like this

```
1. 5.6 hello
2. 8.7 hi
3. (1.3) hey
4. 10 hi
5. (56) hello
```

**Here is what i tried :**

i tried this code that seperates the numbers and letters into 2 different arrays so i can apply the max and min to the numbers

```js
const liArray = ["5.6 hello", "8.7 hi", "1.3 hey", "10 hi", "56 hello"];
const parentElement = document.getElementById("myDiv");

const getNumbers = liArray.map((i) => Number(i.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "")));
const getWords = liArray.map((i) => i.replace(/[0-9.]/g, ""));

const min = Math.min.apply(Math, getNumbers);
const max = Math.max.apply(Math, getNumbers);

getNumbers.forEach((currentValue, index) => {
  const elm = document.createElement('p');
  let text = `${index + 1}. ${(currentValue == min || currentValue == max) ?
 `(${currentValue})` : currentValue}. ${getWords}`;
  elm.innerText = text;
  parentElement.appendChild(elm);
});
```

but it outputs this instead

```
2. 8.7. hello, hi, hey, hi, hello

3. (1.3). hello, hi, hey, hi, hello

4. 10. hello, hi, hey, hi, hello

5. (56). hello, hi, hey, hi, hello
```

Comment: You just need `${getWords[index]}` instead of using the entire array `${getWords}` inside `text`

Comment: why not use an ordered list `<ol>` with `<li>`?

Comment: @NinaScholz yeah i just realised i can use `ol` xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? You just forgot to get element of the getwords array.

```js
const liArray = ["5.6 hello", "8.7 hi", "1.3 hey", "10 hi", "56 hello"];
const parentElement = document.getElementById("myDiv");

const getNumbers = liArray.map((i) => Number(i.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "")));
const getWords = liArray.map((i) => i.replace(/[0-9.]/g, ""));

const min = Math.min.apply(Math, getNumbers);
const max = Math.max.apply(Math, getNumbers);

getNumbers.forEach((currentValue, index) => {
  const elm = document.createElement('p');
  let text = `${index + 1}. ${(currentValue == min || currentValue == max) ?
 `(${currentValue})` : currentValue}. ${getWords[index]}`;
  elm.innerText = text;
  parentElement.appendChild(elm);
});
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: yeah i forgot to use [index] lmao, thanks for helping :D

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your method `getWords` to display words but it is returning an array of all words. Call this method with the index like `${getWords[index]}` to get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an array of numbers and check with this array for min and max value.

```js
const
    array = ["5.6 hello", "8.7 hi", "1.3 hey", "10 hi", "56 hello"],
    values = array.map(s => +s.split(' ', 1)),
    min = Math.min(...values),
    max = Math.max(...values),
    parentElement = document.getElementById("myDiv");

array.forEach((currentValue, index) => {
    const elm = document.createElement('p');
    elm.innerText = `${index + 1}. ${values[index] == min || values[index] == max
        ? currentValue.split(' ').map((s, i) => i ? s : `(${s})`).join(' ')
        : currentValue}`;
  
    parentElement.appendChild(elm);
});
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Version with a real list.

```js
const
    array = ["5.6 hello", "8.7 hi", "1.3 hey", "10 hi", "56 hello"],
    values = array.map(s => +s.split(' ', 1)),
    min = Math.min(...values),
    max = Math.max(...values),
    ol = document.createElement('ol');

document.body.appendChild(ol);

array.forEach((currentValue, index) => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText = values[index] == min || values[index] == max
        ? currentValue.split(' ').map((s, i) => i ? s : `(${s})`).join(' ')
        : currentValue;
  
    ol.appendChild(li);
});
```

Comment: hi thanks for answering, i see that you put all the variables in one variable `const`. is it better than putting `const` on every variable?

Comment: it saves typing. (and looks cleaner.)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```js
const liArray = ["5.6 A", "8.7 B", "1.3 C", "10 D", "56 E"];
const min = liArray.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const cur1 = parseFloat(cur);
  const acc1 = parseFloat(acc);
  return !acc ? cur : acc1 > cur1 ? cur : acc;
  }, null);
  const max = liArray.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const cur1 = parseFloat(cur);
  const acc1 = parseFloat(acc);
  return !acc ? cur : acc1 < cur1 ? cur : acc;
  }, null);
const parentElement = document.getElementById("myDiv");

liArray.forEach((currentValue, index) => {
  const elm = document.createElement('p');
  let text = `${index + 1}. ${(currentValue == min || currentValue == max) ? `(${currentValue.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "")})${currentValue.replace(/[0-9.]/g, "")}` : currentValue}`;
  elm.innerText = text;
  parentElement.appendChild(elm);
});
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

I just change your min-max find method into reduce array method, to get required output